# What exactly does "Dynamic Web Module" facet add to an eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, facet

Everybody in the world, except me, seems to know what exactly the "Dynamic Web Module" facet is adding to a project. Web search reveals tons of responses how to recover from various errors originating in more or less unwanted changes in the version of this facet, but there is hardly any information about what the facet actually does.

So my questions are:

1. What exactly does the "Dynamic Web Module" facet add to my eclipse project?
2. Why should I want this to happen?
3. Why do my colleagues using IntelliJ, Visual Studio Code etc. –where this concept does not seem to exist– have no problem?

Comment: *Are* you having a problem?

Comment: @nitind – No. I’m just having a question. I hate doing things that I don‘t understand for a reason that I do not understand. You happen to have some documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping mind that I didn't decide on these names (and I grumbled about them myself at the time)...  The term dates back to the early J2EE Tutorials, like https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial-update2/doc/WebApp3.html The tutorial would explain that J2EE web modules are the web applications from the then Java Servlet specification.  J2EE loved to subsume the other specs and use its own naming for things that already had names. The doc and tools often followed suit.

It also mentions that they can contain static web resources, and in fact you can run web modules that only contain static resources. So WTP has the concept of a static web module and a dynamic web module, as static web projects and dynamic web projects in Eclipse. The Facet designates a project as being one of the two, and for dynamic modules, which API level it supports and requires at runtime.

Server adapters then have to state which API versions the server types they provide can support.  The Server Tools and validation can then help you avoid deploying to an incompatible server, as well as build against a valid server.  You want to build against a valid server in the same way you want to compile against your intended Java runtime.  It's the most straightforward way to, for example, avoid calling classes and methods that didn't exist at the time.

There's also a Module Core nature that gets added, which supports APIs for describing the deployment details. Details like saying your Java class output folder contents go into WEB-INF/classes, that the jars you select go into WEB-INF/lib and that those static resources go into the application root, all to comply with the layout expected at runtime. That API is meant to be pluggable, so it can be fulfilled by e.g. Maven integration.

The terms in the UI can be changed, but that has its own pain points.  The community tends not to update old videos and tutorials that have been correct for years.